# How are foreign thread-local global variables accessed in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, ffi

For each of the following thread-local storage implementations, how can an external thread-local variable be accessed in Rust programs using the standard ffi mechanisms as exposed by the compiler or standard library?

- C11
- gcc's tls extension
- pthreads
- Windows TLS API

Comment: Can you supplement the library and provide a C function to read and write to those thread_local variables?

Comment: Yes. It's my intention to write a small glue library to deal with thread-local variables if Rust lacks the necessary facilities to do so. However, I prefer to avoid the extra build dependencies if at all possible.

Comment: Any answer would require you to tell us **what threading system you are using and how you are creating thread local variables**. A great way of doing that would be to provide a [MCVE] of the extern code and the Rust code that you've created that shows how you'd like to access it.

Comment: If the thread local variable is declared as `pub` you should be able to access it from everywhere. See [`LocalKey`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html) and [`thread_local`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html) or this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d86305059b6fdb8b212752db4e0b5ee9&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: @rnstlr Sorry, I think you've misunderstood. The thread local variable is defined in an external c library. I want to set that variable in a Rust program.

Comment: I've just generalized this question to be more useful for other people looking for a similar answer.

Comment: @Doe Ah yes, I misunderstood. I added an answer with a C11 _Thread_local solution using gcc.

Answer (score 8):

Rust has a nightly feature, which allows linking to external thread local variables. The stabilization of the feature is tracked [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29594).

## C11 / GCC TLS extension

C11 defines the [`_Thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/_Thread_local) keyword to define [thread-storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) for an object. There also exists a [thread_local](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local) macro alias.

GCC also implements a [Thread Local](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Thread-Local.html#Thread-Local) extension which uses `__thread` as a keyword.

Linking to both an external C11 `_Thread_local` and a gcc `__thread` variable is possible using nightly (tested with `rustc 1.17.0-nightly (0e7727795 2017-02-19)` and gcc 5.4)

```
#![feature(thread_local)]

extern crate libc;

use libc::c_int;

#[link(name="test", kind="static")]
extern {
    #[thread_local]
    static mut test_global: c_int;
}

fn main() {
    let mut threads = vec![];
    for _ in 0..5 {
        let thread = std::thread::spawn(|| {
            unsafe {
                test_global += 1;
                println!("{}", test_global);
                test_global += 1;
            }
        });
        threads.push(thread);
    }

    for thread in threads {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

This allows get access to a variable declared as either of the following:

```
_Thread_local extern int test_global;
extern __local int test_global;
```

The output of the above Rust code will be:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Which is expected, when the variable is defined as thread local.

Comment: Excellent answer. Corresponding tracking issue seems to be https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29594. From the issue it seems that stabilization does not seem likely.